# Is there any better way to but all of this in an array?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner and wanted to make a chess game I just started I think there is a better way to but all the pieces in an array without writing every single one of them like this
my code is so long and ugly please help me

```
public class Chess {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [][] grid = new int[8][8];

        Pieces PB1 = new Pieces(); PB1.Pieces = 6;
        Pieces PB2 = new Pieces(); PB2.Pieces = 6;
        Pieces PB3 = new Pieces(); PB3.Pieces = 6;
        Pieces PB4 = new Pieces(); PB4.Pieces = 6;
        Pieces PB5 = new Pieces(); PB5.Pieces = 6;
        Pieces PB6 = new Pieces(); PB6.Pieces = 6;
        Pieces PB7 = new Pieces(); PB7.Pieces = 6;
        Pieces PB8 = new Pieces(); PB8.Pieces = 6;
        Pieces PW1 = new Pieces(); PW1.Pieces = 6;
        Pieces PW2 = new Pieces(); PW2.Pieces = 6;
        Pieces PW3 = new Pieces(); PW3.Pieces = 6;
        Pieces PW4 = new Pieces(); PW4.Pieces = 6;
        Pieces PW5 = new Pieces(); PW5.Pieces = 6;
        Pieces PW6 = new Pieces(); PW6.Pieces = 6;
        Pieces PW7 = new Pieces(); PW7.Pieces = 6;
        Pieces PW8 = new Pieces(); PW8.Pieces = 6;
        Pieces KB1 = new Pieces(); KB1.Pieces = 2;
        Pieces KW1 = new Pieces(); KW1.Pieces = 2;
        Pieces QB1 = new Pieces(); QB1.Pieces = 1;
        Pieces QW1 = new Pieces(); QW1.Pieces = 1;
        Pieces BB1 = new Pieces(); BB1.Pieces = 3;
        Pieces BB2 = new Pieces(); BB2.Pieces = 3;
        Pieces BW1 = new Pieces(); BW1.Pieces = 3;
        Pieces BW2 = new Pieces(); BW2.Pieces = 3;
        Pieces NB1 = new Pieces(); NB1.Pieces = 4;
        Pieces NB2 = new Pieces(); NB2.Pieces = 4;
        Pieces NW1 = new Pieces(); NW1.Pieces = 4;
        Pieces NW2 = new Pieces(); NW2.Pieces = 4;
        Pieces RB1 = new Pieces(); RB1.Pieces = 5;
        Pieces RB2 = new Pieces(); RB2.Pieces = 5;
        Pieces RW1 = new Pieces(); RW1.Pieces = 5;
        Pieces RW2 = new Pieces(); RW2.Pieces = 5;
    }
}

public class Pieces{
    int type;     // |1 = Queen|   |2 = King|   |3 = Bishop|   |4 = Knight|   |5 = Rook|   |6 = Pawn|
    int movement; // |1 = Pawn Step|   |2 = Pawn Two Steps|   |3 = Pawn Kill|   |4 = Knight|   |5 = Rook|   |6 = Bishop|   |7 = King|
}
```

Comment: What are / is a `Pieces` and why has it a `static` field `pieces`? Can you show that class, too? Please explain your architecture a little.

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. You're creating an `int[]`, but then you're creating `Pieces` (and it should be `Piece`, singular). Are you trying to assign objects where an `int` is needed? You also seem to store metadata in the variable name, which not a good idea. I'd also use `enum` for the type, the `movement` variable seems unnecessary.

Comment: Are you familiar with inheritance? Another option is to create an abstract base class for all the pieces and implement each piece type in child classes. Then you can create an array of the base class to hold all the pieces of each type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn OO principles first, then you are good to go. To just get the idea what you could do

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Chess {

    enum Rank {
        // this time lower case even if these are constants
        a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h
    }

    enum File {
        one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight
    }

    enum FigureColor {
        BLACK, WHITE
    }

    interface Figure {

        FigureColor getFigureColor();

        Collection<FigurePosition> getMovements();

        Figure move(FigurePosition figurePosition);

        FigurePosition getCurrentPosition();

    }

    class FigurePosition {

        Rank rank;
        File file;

        public FigurePosition(Rank rank, File file) {
            this.rank = rank;
            this.file = file;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "FigurePosition{" +
                    "rank=" + rank +
                    ", file=" + file +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    abstract class BasicFigure implements Figure {

        private FigureColor figureColor;
        private List<FigurePosition> movements = new ArrayList<FigurePosition>();

        public BasicFigure(FigureColor figureColor, FigurePosition initialFigurePosition) {
            this.figureColor = figureColor;
            move(initialFigurePosition);
        }

        public FigureColor getFigureColor() {
            return figureColor;
        }

        public Collection<FigurePosition> getMovements() {
            return movements;
        }

        public Figure move(FigurePosition figurePosition) {
            movements.add(figurePosition);
            return this;
        }

        public FigurePosition getCurrentPosition() {
            return movements.get(movements.size()-1);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getClass().getSimpleName() + "{" +
                    "figureColor=" + figureColor +
                    ", currentPosition=" + getCurrentPosition() +
                    ", movements=[" + getMovements().stream().map(FigurePosition::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(",")) + "]'}'";
        }
    }

    class Queen extends BasicFigure {

        public Queen(FigureColor figureColor, FigurePosition initialFigurePosition) {
            super(figureColor, initialFigurePosition);
        }

        @Override
        public Figure move(FigurePosition figurePosition) {
            // you can for example validate movements here
            return super.move(figurePosition);
        }
    }

    class King extends BasicFigure {

        public King(FigureColor figureColor, FigurePosition initialFigurePosition) {
            super(figureColor, initialFigurePosition);
        }
    }

    class Pawn extends BasicFigure {

        public Pawn(FigureColor figureColor, FigurePosition initialFigurePosition) {
            super(figureColor, initialFigurePosition);
        }
    }

    /** add other figure classes here */

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Figure whiteQueen = new Queen(FigureColor.WHITE, new FigurePosition(Rank.d, File.one));
        System.out.println(whiteQueen);
        Figure blackPawn1 = new Pawn(FigureColor.BLACK, new FigurePosition(Rank.a, File.seven));
        blackPawn1.move(new FigurePosition(Rank.a, File.six));
        System.out.println(blackPawn1);
    }

}
```